# Any good way to simplify component wrapped by multiple functions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo

App component has been wrapped by so many functions.

Is there any way to make this look better?

`withstyle(styles)(withRouter(withApollo(connect(App))));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[compose](https://redux.js.org/api/compose#composefunctions):

```
compose(
  withstyle(styles),
  withRouter,
  withApollo,
  connect
)(App);
```